# How to configure hbase using cygwin?

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, hbase

i have configured my `Hadoop` in cygwin now i m trying to configure Hbase 
i have made some changes in hbase-evn.sh as:

```
export JAVA_HOME=C:\\java\\jre
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=C:\\cygwin\\usr\\local\\hbase\\lib\\zookeeper-3.3.2
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=C:\\cygwin\\usr\\local\\hbase\\conf\\regionservers
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

and some changes in hbase-site.xml

```
 <property>
     <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9100/hbase</value>
 </property>

 <property>
     <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
     <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
       <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
       <value>localhost</value>
 </property>

 <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
 </property>
```

now when i m stating my hbase services using command  bin/start-hbase.sh
then the output is as:
[image: output]

can u help me to resolve the problem .

Comment: why don't you run hbase in standalone mode it is much simple to configure and it is perfect for learning HBase.

You can read more about it on http://hbase.apache.org/book/standalone_dist.html

Comment: Which version of hbase are you using?, I have a similar problem with [hbase-0.90.4 and hbase-0.90.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887365/starting-hbase-cygpath-cant-convert-empty-path)

Comment: I think I have answered a similar question by @Osy just now. See if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887365/starting-hbase-cygpath-cant-convert-empty-path/17892502#17892502